# yii : twitteroauth:: error ::: include(Profile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii

I am using a code from this https://github.com/wartron/yii-twitter url,

It shows the error:

> include(Profile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

```
$model = new User;          /*comment from author*/make the user module
$profile=new Profile;       /*comment from author*/since im using the yii user module i have a profile model as well
$profile->regMode = true;
```

Please help sove this issue

edit : My question is totally different this is totally a yii framework question. not a general php question...

Comment: you can create Profile Table for integrate YII - Twitter and otherwise you can remove code in `yii-twitter/protected/controllers/SsoController.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: make sure you have ```'application.modules.user.models.*',``` line in the "import" section of your configuration file.